# Keeping track of what Path mouse event occured

Tags: wpf, events

I'm drawing multiple Path objects to a WPF canvas based on a collection. I want a popup to show with some information of the specific item in the collection on mouse-over the Path. However, I'm not sure how to keep track of which Path the event is triggered on (using sender only gives information on the Path, not which of the collection it was drawn for). As it stands I have this:

Adding the shape & event:

```
For (int i = 0; i < Collection.Count ; i++)
{
    Path p = new Path();
    p.MouseEnter += P_MouseEnter;
    ...
    TrackerCanvas.Children.Add(p);
}
```

and later, the event that is shared for all of them:

```
private void P_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    dialogPopUp.IsOpen = true;
    //no way of knowing which collection object triggered event
}
```

At first I tried extending MouseEventHandler to make a custom object so I could, say, pass some information with the delegate:

```
p.MouseEnter += new MyPathMouseEventHandler(i, P_MouseEnter);
```

But this isn't going to work, as MouseEventHandler is sealed, and the path.MouseEnter needs a MouseEventHandler.

Then I thought, maybe I could extend Path and create MyPath which has a property "IndexOfPath" or some other useful info that I could reference from the sender. Like this:

```
MyPath path = (MyPath)sender;
MyItem = Collection[path.IndexOfPath];
```

However, Path is sealed... So that's out of the window.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: `var path = (Path)sender;`. Shouldn't this be the `Path` object that fired the `MouseEnter`?

Comment: Maybe I should have worded the title better. Yeah, I can find out the Path, but the Path doesn't contain any information about which object the Path was drawn for, if you get what I mean? Not sure how to make the title clearer, but I've edited the description to try explain it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles upon this. In the end, the easiest (not necessarily best?) way to get this was to set the Path's "Tag" property to the associated object instance on creation. From then on, this can be accessed through any events through the event source.